# Раненые, калеченые / раненные, калеченные

Tags: орфография, нн

Как правильно?

`Все эти раненые, калеченые и контуженые получат помощь.`

`Все эти раненные, калеченные и контуженные получат помощь.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Вот что имеется в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:

> **3.** Причастия не на *-ованный* (*-ёванный, -еванный*) глаголов несовершенного вида (они образуются только от бесприставочных глаголов) и соотносительные с ними прилагательные пишутся по-разному: причастия с ***нн***, прилагательные — с одним ***н***, напр.: *гружённые дровами повозки, жаренная на масле рыба, писанная маслом картина*... но: *гружёная баржа, жареная рыба, писаная красавица* <...>
> По этому правилу пишутся формы двувидовых глаголов *контузить, крестить* и *ранить.* Ср.: *контуженный в голову боец, тяжело раненный солдат, раненный в ногу солдат, только что крещённый младенец,* но: *контуженый командир, раненый солдат, крещёный ребёнок.*

• Из Нацкорпуса (с одной **н**, без зависимых слов):

*Там **эти раненые** союзники крайне возбуждены, они недолюбливают своего врача* (Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек);
*Здесь, на этой улице, еще недавно, **контуженые, раненые** солдаты учили новобранцев, кричали...* (Максим Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина);
*Худые, **калеченые**, рваные, с голодным и вороватым блеском в глазах, они торговали чем ни попадя...* (Владимир Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина).

• Из Нацкорпуса (с **нн**, с зависимыми словами):

*...**эти раненные в боях** девочки лежат вместе на 4-м этаже госпиталя* (Эд. Поляновский. Ожидание счастья. Дневники и письма военного фельдшера Татьяны Атабек);
*И они, Федя, войной не увеченные, **на фронте не калеченные*** (В. Г. Галактионова. Спящие от печали);
*Игорь ухаживал за ранеными, **тяжело контуженные** успокаивались при этом худеньком черноглазом мальчике* (А. Д. Сахаров. Воспоминания).

■ Думаю, правильно с одной **н**:
*Все эти раненые, калеченые и контуженые получат помощь.*

[Двойное **н** и одно **н** в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени и соотносительных с ними прилагательных. Полные формы](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52)

Answer (score 2):

**Как вариант:**

*Все эти раненые, калеченые и **контуженные** получат помощь.*

Это субстантивированные прилагательные (то есть **существительные**).

В толковом словаре **Ефремовой:**

**[Контуженный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/176977/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)**, м. разг. Тот, кто получил контузию.

**[Раненый](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/235500/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)**, м. Тот, кто получил ранение.

А ***калеченого/калеченного*** нет.  Может, его нельзя включать в однородный ряд?

В словаре РАН указаны **только прилагательные,** но не существительные.

Comment: Я думаю, лучше — так будет более по-рановски, по-моему, — писать с одним *н*.

Comment: Worse or better, but the intrigue remains, because Efremova will not just say that. The words differ in some ways, including in style. You can write something, but why not pay attention to this fact, right?

Comment: Sharon, а мне непонятно, почему вы пишете *контуженые* с Н, а приводите словарную статью с НН.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
Совершенно случайно, слова так похожи. Кстати, вы тоже "по-рановски" напишете, не правда ли? Верно, и задумываться не будете, мелочи ведь!

Comment: Нет, Sharon. Если появится необходимость в написании этих слов, да ещё в одном предложении, тогда и подумаю, что лучше подходит.

Comment: Ещё момент. [В словаре РАН](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=Контуженый) есть существительное: **КОНТУЖЕНЫЙ,** -ого; ***м.*** Тот, кто получил контузию. *В госпиталь доставили несколько контуженых.* // *Раненый*, кстати, там тоже есть как существительное. Может, Ефремова что-то упустила? Почему вы в данном случае верите этому словарю, ведь вы же сами очень часто приводите данные РАН?

Comment: В орф. словаре РАН есть прилагательные, а субст. слов там нет. Они есть у Кузнецова  и у Ефремовой, их надо сравнивать.

Comment: По крайней мере, **раненый 2,** -ого  в орф. словаре там есть.

Comment: У Ефремовой еще стиль разный, контуженный – разг.  Мне этот автор вообще нравится. зря говорить не будет. Но ладно, закроем тему и все пишем по словарю РАН. И без этого проблем хватает... Спасибо вам за внимание.

Comment: Я всё равно вам плюс поставил (когда поправили ответ). Спасибо за неравнодушное отношение практически к каждому вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо за плюс, я догадалась.  По психологии вот собираюсь пойти...

Answer (score 1):

***Все эти раненые, калеченые и контуженые получат помощь.***

В словаре «Грамоты» есть все варианты написания.

См. [*раненый*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) и [*раненный*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[*контуженый*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) и [*контуженный*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[*калеченый*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) и [*калеченный*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]